# Installing python3-netcdf4 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, python3, source-packages

When I type `sudo apt-get install python3-netcdf4` on Ubuntu 14.04, I get a message `Unable to locate package python3-netcdf4`. How do I install `python3-netcdf4` on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: That package does not exist for Ubuntu 14.04. For example, you can see that trusty is missing from this list at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-netcdf4.

Comment: @edwinksl - I just need netcd4 on python3.4. How do I install netcdf  for python?

Comment: I see that netCDF4 is available on PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netCDF4), so I would suggest installing it using `pip` inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python3-netcdf4` package does not exist for Ubuntu 14.04 as you can see from http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3-netcdf4. However, netCDF4 can be found on PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netCDF4).

Instead of using `sudo pip` to install Python packages at the system level, I recommend installing them via `pip` in a virtualenv. First, install `virtualenv` using `apt-get`. Second, create a virtualenv and activate it. Last, use `pip` to install `netCDF4`. The code to do so is given by:

```
sudo apt-update && sudo apt-get install virtualenv
cd ~/<desired directory>
virtualenv venv -p python3
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -U pip
pip install netCDF4
```

Replace `<desired directory>` with where you want to create the virtualenv.